# Can we use custom cell editor as similar of "agLargeTextCellEditor"?

Tags: angular7, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

[image: This is TextArea appers when we use "agLargeTextCellEditor"]

I have use these lines of code for attached image textarea in Address header column .

`````````````
      ````````
           "headerName: "Address",
            field: "Address",
            width: 350,
           **cellEditor: 'agLargeTextCellEditor'**

    ````````````
`````````````

But limitation of "agLargeTextCellEditor" is it accept only 200 character. but my requirement is upto 500 character. So can we use any custom cell editor in ag-grid? or any alternative solution for it?

Note: I know some of you will suggest me to go with "agRichSelectCellEditor" but it is available in ag-Grid Enterprise only so i can't use this.

For more information refer https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-provided-cell-editors/#agtextcelleditor-agpopuptextcelleditor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the agLargeTextCellEditor says that the number of characters, as well as the number of rows and columns, is configurable. The default 'maxLength' is 200, but you can supply your own value.

I haven't tried this, but from the documentation, it looks like you should modify your columnDef to look like:

```
{
   headerName: 'Address',
   field: 'Address',
   width: 350,
   cellEditor: 'agLargeTextCellEditor'
   cellEditorParams: {maxLength: 500}
}
```